# Extensive use of global variables in js codebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture

I've been tasked with refactoring/simplifying the architecture of a (relatively) large node.js codebase and it makes ample use of global variables. I don't have much experience with javascript so just wanted to get a general sense of whether this is indeed super confusing and bad practise or if I'm in the wrong.

Here's a dummy example of a pattern I see throughout the codebase:

eg. 3 files: A.js, B.js, C.js:

A.js:

```
A_init = () => {
    // sets global variable a
    a = 1
}

exports.A_init = A_init
```

B.js:

```
B_init = () => {
    // sets global variable b
    b = 2
}

exports.B_init = B_init
```

C.js:

```
C_init = () => {
    // sets global variable c
    // depends on global variables a and b being set
    c = a + b
}

exports.C_init = C_init
```

In reality there are many more files in the library (around 40) and some are thousands of lines long with random functions spread throughout the code which set variables at a global level which other library files have methods to utilise.

So for eg. if a developer wishes to utilise the library, they might write something like this:

UserScript.js

```
const A = require("./A");
const B = require("./B");
const C = require("./C");

A.A_init()
C.C_init()
B.B_init()

someMethod = () => console.log(a, b, c) // expected: 1, 2, 3 actual: ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

My experience of using the codebase is these sorts of ReferenceErrors surface very frequetly due to people either not knowing they need to call certain functions in order to set global variables other functions depend on or calling them in the wrong sequence.

There are probably around 50-100 such global variables and it's a nightmare to try and extract out... If this question is too vague I appologise, but what strategies would you suggest I adopt to address this? Is some use of global variables like this acceptable? Are there standards people adopt to constrain their usage? Would adopting a more OO approach and using classes/constructors be something you would recommend here?

I have tried sourcing for answers online but I could not get any. I hope to find answers here.

Comment: Your intuition that these globals like these are bad is absolutely correct.  Nodejs uses a module architecture so you can specifically avoid this.  Modules can import and export values from other modules without using a single global and all initialization is done by the module that exports the value.  Also, modules can initialize their values when they load, without someone else needing to call a `.init()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caleb.

- Start with writing regression tests, so you can be confident not to
  break too much when you refactor.
- Find out where and how certain variables are used. Add comments. Give
  those global variables better names, if they don't have already, and
  make sure the same variable isn't used for different purposes.
- Then start replacing the use of global variables by explicit
  parameter passing and explicit return values. That will reduce the
  temporal coupling issues you showed in the question.
- If you now notice some of your functions becoming too many
  parameters, identify parameters which are always passed as a group,
  make a data structure out of them, so you can pass them together.
  Make sure that data structure stays a useful abstraction.
- If you find certain operations which work mainly on those data
  structures alone, convert the data structure into a class and
  implement the operations as member functions.

Comment: I will definitely follow this! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In general you need to **avoid using global variables** (50-100 is definitely a lot) as they may be overwritten by other functions (specially that JavaScript is an asynchronous and concurrent programming language), and overusing it makes the code non-readable.

JavaScript supports a wide range of programming patterns such as OOP, Functional programming, dependency injection, etc.

To get more information on Javascript best practices visit the following link:
https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices

Based on your exact needs, maybe you could replace these bad patterns with patterns like modular-programming, object-oriented-programming, dependency injection, etc.